# How do I use assertions here?

Tags: java, assertion

This java program Calculates the sum of a geometric sequence q = (1/2) = 0.5 n is a natural number (including 0).  Everywhere where it says "// here" assertions should now be added

Topic is the geometric series math
My idea was after the method declaration to write  assert int =1; but its wrong

```
public static double geoReihe(int n) {
    // here 
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        result += Math.pow(0.5, i);
        // here 
    }
    // here 
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: We can't really know your requirements here. You should know best what values are valid here. The first one should probably make sure that `n` is not negative?

Comment: When you say "Everywhere where it says..." what exactly is **it**?  We can't second-guess your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one makes sense and you can put `assertTrue(n >= 0)` there. If you can calculate the result based using some formula, you can use `assertEquals(put-here-the-value-calculated-by-formula, result)` for the third one. The second one can not be asserted AFAIU.

```
public static double geoReihe(int n) {
    // here
    assertTrue(n >= 0);
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        result += Math.pow(0.5, i);
        // here
    }
    // here
    assertEquals(put-here-the-value-calculated-by-formula, result);
    return result;
```

}

Comment: Where are these methods coming from?  Junit?  OP - correct me if I'm wrong but that code didn't look like a test harness to me.